# Problem using ArrayReferenceField with djongo and django

Tags: python, django, django-models, djongo

I'am trying to create an application with django using djongo to communicate with mongodb. I have the following model:

```
from djongo import models
from django import forms

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = (
            '__all__'
        )

class MetaData(models.Model):
    # pub_date = models.DateField()
    # mod_date = models.DateField()
    n_pingbacks = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MetaDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MetaData
        fields = (
            '__all__'
        )

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = (
            'name', 'email'
        )

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=Blog,
        model_form_class=BlogForm
    )
    meta_data = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=MetaData,
        model_form_class=MetaDataForm
    )

    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()

    authors = models.ArrayReferenceField(
        to=Author,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    n_comments = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

But when I use django admin to create a new entry here is the error that I get:

> TypeError at /admin/app/entry/add/ int() argument must be a string, a
>   bytes-like object or a number, not 'set' Request Method:  POST Request
>   URL:  http://localhost:8000/admin/app/entry/add/ Django Version:  2.1.3
>   Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:   int() argument must be a
>   string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set' Exception
>   Location: C:\Users\scg\Documents\Rest_project\envschool\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py
>   in get_prep_value, line 965 Python
>   Executable:   C:\Users\scg\Documents\Rest_project\envschool\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version:   3.7.1 Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\scg\Documents\Rest_project\djongoproj2', 
>   'C:\Users\scg\Documents\Rest_project\envschool\Scripts\python37.zip',
>   'C:\Users\scg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs',
>   'C:\Users\scg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib', 
>   'C:\Users\scg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32', 
>   'C:\Users\scg\Documents\Rest_project\envschool', 
>   'C:\Users\scg\Documents\Rest_project\envschool\lib\site-packages']

Please how can I resolve this.

I'm using django 2.1.3 and djongo 1.2.30

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. I solved it by downgrading to Django 2.0.